# Capistrano picking old Ruby version after updating 2.5.1 to 3.0.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, capistrano, puma

I recently updated my Ruby on Rails application from Ruby version 2.5.1 to 3.0.4. I made sure to update the Ruby version in **deploy.rb** and **config/deploy/production.rb** files. However, when I try to deploy the application using the **cap production deploy** command, Capistrano is still picking up the old Ruby version (2.5.1), and I'm encountering the following error:

```
rvm 1.29.9 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]
ruby-2.5.1
ruby exit status: 1 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
ruby stdout: Nothing written
ruby stderr: Unknown ruby interpreter version (do not know how to handle): 3.0.4.
Unknown ruby interpreter version (do not know how to handle): 3.0.4.
Ruby 3.0.4 is not installed.
```

I've already confirmed that Ruby 3.0.4 is installed on the server. What could be causing Capistrano to ignore the updated Ruby version and how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: How did you update Ruby? And did you update Ruby on your local machine too?

Comment: installed the Ruby new version with RVM and updated the .ruby-version file at both (server and local) machines, and also updated the bundle.

Comment: When you `ssh` into the target machine what does `ruby --version` say? It's also worth testing without a login shell, as in `ssh x@y ruby --version` as sometimes your RVM is set up for login shells only.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone with this problem and using RVM. Try `rvm use --default NEW_VERSION`

Maybe capistrano is using RVM default ruby version, so if you uninstalled or removed the previous version, just update the default with the new one.